# Store function result to variable for later use in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Considering the time I've been using PHP I feel shame for asking this, but it seems I'm way too tired to solve it by myself at this moment.

I have a php variable function that gets an CSV file and stores the data into an array.

```
$csvdata = function(){
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
}
```

This array is used by other functions in different situations.

The thing is that I though this functions will run just once, but I just noticed it runs every time I use the var $csvdata.

What I want is to create a self evoked function that runs only once and store the data into an array that I can use as many times as needed without PHP re-doing the process of getting the csv and storing the data every time I use $csvdata.

Its really weird because I feel like if my brain is playing a joke on me...
(Brain: "It's obvious... I know the answer but I wont tell you")

Sorry pals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call newly created functions on the fly with [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$csvdata = call_user_func(function(){
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
});
```

Then just reference `$csvdata` as a variable (without parenthesis).

#### Explanation

The documentation calls the argument to `call_user_func` a callback, and that is what it is: you pass a function reference to it, and it is the implementation of `call_user_func` that calls your function for you ("calling you back"). The function reference can be an inline, anonymous function (like above).

But it can also be a variable representing a function:

```
$func = function(){
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
};
$csvdata = call_user_func($func);
```

Or, it can be a string, which holds the name of the function:

```
function myFunc(){
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
};
$csvdata = call_user_func('myFunc');
```

All of these do the same: your function gets called. You can even tell `call_user_func` which arguments to pass to your function:

```
function myFunc($arg){
    echo $arg;
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
};
$csvdata = call_user_func('myFunc', 'hello');
```

The above will `echo` 'hello'.

I provide these variants just for information, as your interest is in the inline function argument. Also then you can pass arguments:

```
$csvdata = call_user_func(function($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1 . "," . $arg2;
    // Get CSV data to array
    return $array;
}, 'hello', 'there');
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot It works! Could you provide some explanation in your answer of why using call_user_func() did the trick? I was reading the documentation but it is very poor to give me an idea of why now it's running just once. Just for future reference... Thanks again!

Comment: call_user_func is used for calling the function whose name you don't know  if you have a  funcion with name you can call it by just calling its name

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I would be lying if I say that I understand your comment LOL

Comment: see my answer then you can understand the differnece

Answer (score 0):

you can give a name to the function and make a call like this

```
  function csv(){
        // Get CSV data to array
        return $array;
    }

    $csvdata=csv();
```

Comment: This wont work. Is exactly the same I want to avoid. This way every time you call $csvdata php will run csv(). In my case, this means it will load the csv file and work on it every time I use this var.

Comment: Not true, the function `csv` will only be called once as `$csvdata` will hold an array and not a `closure` like in your example

Comment: @luis see the difference between your code and this answer

Comment: Arun and @DarkBee you guys are correct. This is why resting is an important part of life. I though my version was somehow a shorthanded version of yours, but now I see there's a difference. I'm going to research a bit about `closure` to get a better understanding of when it should be used. Now I think this is the correct answer given the fact that I was wrongly using 'closure'. Thanks pals!